# How to test your web applications on mobile?

Tags: html, css, mobile

I don't have money to buy mobile phones, iPhone, etc, but I do want to make my web applications available to mobile devices. Are there some software to stimulate these devices, or what should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[BlackBerry](https://www.blackberry.com/Downloads/entry.do?code=060AD92489947D410D897474079C1477) [Iphone](http://www.genuitec.com/mobile/) and [Android](http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk-windows-1.5_r3.zip), you can use these simulators and emulators for testing.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, there are emulators you can use. For instance, you could use have a look here for some device images from Microsoft http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=3d6f581e-c093-4b15-ab0c-a2ce5bffdb47&displaylang=en You can test on various screen sizes.

Also an interesting site is http://www.testiphone.com

Comment: http://www.testiphone.com just seems to be loading sites in a iframe roughly the same dimensions as an iPhone screen, so you can't tell that Safari on the iPhone will render it like that.

Comment: if you use testiphone in safari browser, you have a similar render on iphone :-P

Comment: @fravelgue: Not really. While iPhone uses Safari, I would need to be sure to use the exact same version of Safari for testing. I have no idea what versions of Safari iPhone uses and iPhone is just one mobile device on the market.

Comment: @Yower, yeah you are right but it is good aproximation. You could change user agent in safari too. But emulators are always aproximations. If you need more then real testing!

Answer (score 2):

My first testing platform is Firefox [with](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/59) [his](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1345) [extensions](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/62) with help of [mobiready](http://mobiready.com/l). You could use Openwave emulator (it is difficult find direct link) and [Nokia SDK 40 Series](http://www.forum.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/cc48f9a1-f5cf-447b-bdba-c4d41b3d05ce/Series_40_Platform_SDKs.html). Althought this is a old and crapy software. You could use windows mobile emulator too.

Answer (score 0):

depending on your scope & budget, deviceanywhere might be an option? i've got no experience with them myself, but I know a number of suppliers of ours (I work for a telco in europe) use their [subscription-based test center on the web](http://www.deviceanywhere.com/mobile-application-testing.html).

the product that might suit your needs would be 'test center' and there's a specific 'web developer' package that you could choose.